# TextView dynamic height and y-coordinate is not working

Tags: swift, textview

Hello I am working on `textview`. I have a set content for it with `attributed text`. Based on which screen it will be played the textview height should be adjusted to fit screen width, I am using the frame as

```
mytextView.frame = CGrect(x: 0, y: 800, width: view.bounds.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

the textview height is adjusted accordingly but I have `two issues`

1) textview always place at the top of the view and mixed up with other labels. I want the x:0 & y:800 for the textView

2) how to determine the modified height of the textview so as to set the constraint for scrollview (I don't want the textview to scroll, i.e. a fixed height to its contentsize)

please let me know why the frame x and y are not working?

thanks

Comment: Take a look into intrinsicContentSize, maybe it helps: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help joe, I did find an answer,

I changed in the viewdidload as 
mytextView.frame = CGrect(x: 0, y: 800, width: view.bounds.width, height: 200)

and mytextView.isScrollenable = false

so that viewcontroller calculate what should be the actual height of the mytextView

and in

viewdidlayoutsubviews

i used contentsize to adjust the height of mytestView, also I used this height to determine what should be the scrolling height scrollView